# How can I disable the exit confirmation while trying to quit w3m?

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, w3m

Is there a way to remove `Do you want to exit w3m? (y/n)` from prompting after I press `q` to exit the application?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `-o confirm_qq=false` option on the command line.

Example:

```sh
$ w3m -o confirm_qq=false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can quit without confirmation by pressing `Q` instead.
Found this in the manual [here](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/MANUAL) or `man w3m`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your `~/.w3m/config`:

```
confirm_qq false
```

Answer (score 0):

`Q` is default to quit without confirm but if you want lower `q` to do the same just remap your hotkey

```
$EDITOR ~/.w3m/keymap
keymap q EXIT
```